# Appending '0' using concat does not seem to work

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a program that compares two integer value's length with this extension method

```cs
public static int NumDigits(this int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        n = (n == int.MinValue) ? int.MaxValue : -n;
    }
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    if (n < 100) return 2;
    if (n < 1000) return 3;
    if (n < 10000) return 4;
    if (n < 100000) return 5;
    if (n < 1000000) return 6;
    if (n < 10000000) return 7;
    if (n < 100000000) return 8;
    return n < 1000000000 ? 9 : 10;
}
```

And it works perfectly. When I print the value of `num1.numDigits()`, the value returns 4 (it is worth '1111'. And my other integer: `num2.numDigits()` returns 2 (it is 11). This is great but when I actually compare them:

```cs
int[] rawNum2 = Arrays.DigitArr(num2);

if (num1.NumDigits() > num2.NumDigits())
{
    int diff = num1.NumDigits() - num2.NumDigits();
    for (int i = 1; i < diff; i++)
    {
        rawNum2.Append(0);
    }

    reversedNum2 = rawNum2.Reverse();

}
```

reversedNum2 is still '11' when it should be '0011'.

This is the class I compiled and used.

```cs
public static int[] Append(this int[] source, int value)
{
    int[] newValue = source;
    newValue = newValue.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray();
    return newValue;
}

public static int[] Reverse(this int[] array)
{
    int[] arr = array;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length / 2; i++)
    {
      int tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[arr.Length - i - 1];
      arr[arr.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }

    return arr;
}

public static int[] DigitArr(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return new int[1] { 0 };

    var digits = new List<int>();
    for (; n != 0; n /= 10)
        digits.Add(n % 10);

    var arr = digits.ToArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: To determine number of digits I suggest `Math.Abs(n).ToString().Length`

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a simpler way!

Comment: How is `Array` defined?  (in `int[] rawNum2 = Arrays.DigitArr(num2);`)?

Comment: @isXander Also, no need for such loop, this is simple operation called padding. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Luuk It is the class I put all my methods into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are discarding the return value of the `Append` method.
Change

```
rawNum2.Append(0);
```

to

```
rawNum2 = rawNum2.Append(0);
```

inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Now it is '011'. Not '0011'. num1 is '1111' and num2 is '11' Why is this? @PetervanderHeijden

Comment: @isXander Loop `for (int i = 1; i < diff; i++)` should start with `int i = 0` :)

Comment: Thanks. I thought as the way I was returning the numDigits it would always start at 1

Answer (score 1):

Your loop could be and should be simplified to:

```
rawNum2 = rawNum2.PadRight(num1.NumDigits(), '0')
```

Comment: rawNum2 isn't a string its an array.

Answer (score 0):

To get the reversedNum2 as 0011 change your loop as below.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= diff; i++)
{
rawNum2=rawNum2.Append(0);
}
```

I made two changes changed the for loop to use i<=diff instead of i < diff
and assigning the return value from Append() method into the rawNum2.